# Does SL(3,q) have a subgroup of order $q^3.(q^3-1)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $q=p^n$ for $p>3$.I want to know whether the group $G_2(q)$ has a subgroup of order $q^3.(q^3-1)$. First I look the paper of Peter Kleidman. In this paper Kleidman determined all maximal subgroups of $G_2(q)$. So it seems to me that the only subgroup of $G_2(q)$(up to conjugacy) that contains a group of order $q^3.(q^3-1)$ may be $SL(3,q)$.

Comment: The maximal subgroup of $G_2(q)$ is ${\rm SL}(3,q).2$ rather than just ${\rm SL}(3,q)$, and there is also a subgroup ${\rm SU}(3,q).2$, so you would need to consider that one too. But the answer is no anyway. The maximal subgroups of ${\rm SL}^{\pm}(3,q)$ have been known for a lot longer than thsoe of ${\rm G}_2(q)$.

Comment: @derek holt I know the group SL^+(3,q) and I am sure that there is no subgroup of  SL^+(3,q) of order $q^3(q^3-1)$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been answered in a comment.